# Nestjs + Swagger: How to add a custom option to @ApiProperty

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs, openapi, nestjs-swagger

Is it possible to add a custom option to @ApiProperty decorator?

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

class Animal {

  @ApiProperty({
    type: String,
    description: 'animal name',
    'x-description': 'some information' // how to add a cutom option 'x-description' ?
  })
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: [doc](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/master/lib/interfaces/open-api-spec.interface.ts) `SchemaObject`.

Comment: @EmptyBrain I can't see anything about a custom option there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/195#issuecomment-526215840

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

type SwaggerDecoratorParams = Parameters<typeof ApiProperty>;
type SwaggerDecoratorMetadata = SwaggerDecoratorParams[0];
type Options = SwaggerDecoratorMetadata & DictionarySwaggerParameters;
type DictionarySwaggerParameters = { 'x-property'?: string };

export const ApiPropertyX = (params: Options) => {
  return ApiProperty(params);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i fully understand, but If you are talking about [openapi's extensions](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/). Take a look at this: https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/195

Comment: I don't catch how to use Extension decorator to add a custom attribute. I've created a custom decorator than extends ApiProperty like https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/195#issuecomment-526215840 and it works well.

Comment: not sure i fully understand what you mean.